# Create an Entity Type and an Association from the same table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

Is it possible to have both an entity type and a many-many association backed by the same table? I’ve tried a couple different approaches and they all fail with different errors.

First I tried creating the model from the database then creating an association in the designer.[image]

It gives me the proper `Foos` and `Bars` navigation properties, but it's not backed by any table and fails when I try to execute a query.

```
Model1.msl(3,4) : error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - BarFoo.
```

So I tried mapping the association to the FooBar table in the designer. Only `FooREF` and `BarREF` are part of the association, but EF expects the primary key to be mapped as well.

```
ERROR (3025): Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line 32: Must specify mapping for all key properties (FooBar.ObjectID) of table FooBar.
```

Since I’m not able to map the ObjectID and RowVersion, I tried to exclude them by using a [QueryView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798(v=vs.100).aspx) in the edmx.

```
<edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="TestModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="TestEntities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Bars">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="TestModel.Bar">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Bar">
                <ScalarProperty Name="ObjectID" ColumnName="ObjectID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Count" ColumnName="Count" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="RowVersion" ColumnName="RowVersion" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Foos">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="TestModel.Foo">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Foo">
                <ScalarProperty Name="ObjectID" ColumnName="ObjectID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="RowVersion" ColumnName="RowVersion" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="FooBars">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="TestModel.FooBar">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="FooBar">
                <ScalarProperty Name="ObjectID" ColumnName="ObjectID" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="RowVersion" ColumnName="RowVersion" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="BarREF" ColumnName="BarREF" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="FooREF" ColumnName="FooREF" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <AssociationSetMapping Name="BarFoo" TypeName="TestModel.BarFoo" >
            <EndProperty Name="Foo">
              <ScalarProperty Name="ObjectID" ColumnName="FooREF" />
            </EndProperty>
            <EndProperty Name="Bar">
              <ScalarProperty Name="ObjectID" ColumnName="BarREF" />
            </EndProperty>
            <QueryView>
              SELECT VALUE TestModel.BarFoo(CREATEREF(TestEntities.Foos, row(f.FooREF), TestModel.Foo), CREATEREF(TestEntities.Bars, row(f.BarREF), TestModel.Bar))
              FROM TestModelStoreContainer.FooBar AS f
            </QueryView>
          </AssociationSetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
```

But despite the QueryView element being documented, its addition causes the schema validation to fail.

```
MappingException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
<File Unknown>(39,8) : error 2025: XML Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error Information : The element 'AssociationSetMapping' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs' has invalid child element 'QueryView' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs'. List of possible elements expected: 'Condition, ModificationFunctionMapping' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs'..
```

Is there a strategy I'm missing here? In the end I'd like to be able to treat `FooBar` as an entity while also keeping the `Foos` and `Bars` navigation properties. Is this possible?

Comment: No sure what you mean by *but EF expects the primary key to be mapped as well*. Mapping the explicit junction table is extremely easy with Code First, but I guess there should not be a problem to map it in the edmx designer as well.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's how I understood the error. The Primary key of the FooBar table is `ObjectID`, but it is not included in the association mapping.

Comment: Sorry, I've just saw you are trying to have both `Foos`, `Bars` **and** `FooBars` navigation properties. I don't think it's possible in EF, you could either have just `Foos` and `Bars` with implicit link table, or just `FooBars` and explicit `FooBar` entity.

Comment: I might be able to work with just the `Foos` and `Bars` navigation properties and get rid of the `FooBar` entity. That still causes mapping issues though. I think I could get around it by removing the unused columns from the storage mapping, but then I would have to do that every time I update the model from the database.